# Excel/VBA: How to paste SQL query with proper string formatting

Tags: sql, string, vba, excel

I've been writing some pretty long SQL queries in notepad and then pasting them into my VBA code as-is and then formatting the multi-line string correctly each line at a time. For example...

In my text editor, the query looks like this.

```
SELECT 
      a,
      b,
      c,
      ...,
      n
FROM
      table1,
      table2,
      ...,
      tableN
WHERE
      etc
```

Then pasting this into the VBA editor and manually adding **sqlStr = sqlStr & " .... "** to every line.

```
sqlStr = "               SELECT "
sqlStr = sqlStr & "          a,"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "          b,"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "          c,"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "          ...,"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "          n"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "      FROM"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "          table1,"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "          table2,"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "          ...,"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "          tableN"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "      WHERE"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "          etc"
```

Does anyone know of a tool that will let me automatically wrap the VBA string stuff around my query (instead of adding it manually)? I imagine there's a web site somewhere for that, but I can't find it.

I could rig up something in Vi, but I can't guarantee that I'll be doing this on a computer that I'll have rights to install Vi on.

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to look at **[SQLinForm](http://sqlinform.com/free_online_sw.html)**. Among other formats, it allows you to format SQL for use in VB/VBA

Comment: No problem, happy to help :) the pay for version is worth it if you use it a lot

Comment: Almost two years later... I've purchased a license to SQLinform. Well worth the price! Not only for outputting SQL in VBA string format, but also for auto-formatting badly formatted SQL statements.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do `sqlStr = sqlStr &` on every line. Just continue the one statement like this:

```
sqlStr = "SELECT a, b, c,..., n " & _
         "  FROM table1, table2,..., tableN " & _
         " WHERE etc"
```

You can have up to 25 lines on a single statement this way.

Also, I don't think you are doing yourself any favours by formatting long queries with every item on a separate line. I take a more moderate approach, trying to show a bit more structure without using too many lines. Here is a bit of code from a recent project. (It is used to set the RowSource for a combo box)

```
q = "SELECT NurseID, NurseName FROM " & _
    " (SELECT DISTINCT 0 as NurseID,  '-- choose nurse --' as NurseName FROM tblNurse) " & _
    "UNION " & _
    " (SELECT DISTINCT N.NurseID AS NurseID, FirstName & ' ' & LastName AS NurseName " & _
    "  FROM tblNurse AS N INNER JOIN tblBookings AS B" & _
    "  ON N.NurseID=B.NurseID " & _
    "  WHERE B.BDate >= " & Date_To_SQL(txtStartDate) & _
    "    AND B.BDate <= " & Date_To_SQL(txtEndDate) & ") " & _
    "ORDER BY NurseName"
```

This also demonstrates the use of aliases to make the SQL shorter and more readable.
It is pretty quick to insert all the quotes and "& _" in the VBA editor, if you put them in the clipboard and use the mouse and keyboard to Click, Ctrl-V, Click, Ctrl-V buzzing down through the rows.

Answer (score 1):

A quick-and-dirty solution:

Copy the text into cell A1 of a clean spreadsheet. Each line will land in a cell going down from A1.

```
In B1 put ="sqlString ="""&A1&""""
In B2 put ="sqlString=sqlString&"""&A2&""""
```

Copy/drag B2 down to the end of the column of text.

Copy and paste the resulting column B into your code.

You could also edit your sql fragments straight into column A of a blank Excel sheet instead of notepad, and save a step.

If you'd rather do it with code, this VBA will make Column B from Column A:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub makeSqlStmt()
    Dim r
    Dim n
    Dim i
    Const s = "sqlString = """
    Const t = "sqlString = sqlString & """
    Set r = Range("a1")
    Range("B1") = s & r & """"
    n = r.CurrentRegion.Rows.count
    For i = 1 To n - 1
        r.Offset(i, 1) = t & r.Offset(i, 0) & """"
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you wanted to take it straight from the notepad file, you could replace the For loop with code to read the file.

Comment: Thanks Marc! This looks good. I'm going to use this if I'm dealing with any sensitive information that shouldn't get pasted to sqlinform mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

here is the result generated automatically by [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)(free online sql formatter)

```
var1 = ""
var1 = var1 & "SELECT a, " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "       b, " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "       c " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "FROM   table1, " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "       table2, " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "       tablen " & vbCrLf
var1 = var1 & "WHERE  a > 1 "
```

Answer (score 0):

Any text editor with a macro/record feature will let you automate this -- VS.NET, TextPad, Notepad++.  For, the last see: [Notepad++ Macros](http://karimfatehi.blogspot.com/2009/06/notepad-macros-video.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have Excel installed if you're doing VBA.

You could write a spreadsheet where you paste the SQL in column A, and use the `CONCATENATE()` excel formula function to add the VBA code. Then you can just copy and paste it into your app.